# How do I grab info from one table while still adding values?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I'm working on a project and am trying to grab a key from another table while still grabbing from the values given. For example...

```
INSERT INTO Essay (student_ID, student_essay) VALUES (`Students.student_ID`, 'I WANNA BE THE VERY BEST');
```

I need to grab the student_ID from the Students table (otherwise the numbers will be off since student_ID is auto-increment), but I need to be able to insert the value of the essay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `Max(id)` function.

You can use Max(id) function also it will return max id and you are using auto increment so offcorse it will return last id and that last id you can insert in 2nd table, like:

```
INSERT INTO Essay (student_ID, student_essay) 
       VALUES ((SELECT MAX(s_id) from Students), 'I WANNA BE THE VERY BEST');
```

here is S_id means you need to provide that id which you want to use in Students table.

Comment: I need the LAST_INSERT_ID() from the Students table so I can make it the same from the Parents table (The parents are linked to the right student). How can I store the LAST_INSERT_ID from Students so I can insert it as a value? @PiyushGupta

Comment: I added the full SQL statement to my question. I am now getting a different error.

Comment: @ribre817, Please revert your question back, max(id) is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want, but probably you only need an INSERT from SELECT.

```
INSERT INTO Essay (Student_id, Student_essay)
SELECT student_id, ? student_essay
FROM Student
WHERE name = ?;
```

You can find this in the docs: [Insert from select MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)

Question Marks represent the values that you will send from the application.

This should solve your problem:

```
INSERT INTO Essay (Student_id, Student_essay)
SELECT student_id, 'I WANNA BE THE VERY BEST' student_essay
FROM Student
WHERE email = 'asdajo@hota.com';
```

Comment: I need to grab the student_ID from another table (Students), but that table doesn't contain Student_essay. I need to type that in myself. @georgeos

Comment: Can you please explain at detail how does it work? Or do you have a list of essays and each one is related to the Student_id in the order defined for those essays?

Comment: I have a table named Students that contains information about a student. Everytime I insert a new student into the table, the auto_increment variable "student_id" increments. So the first student I enter is student 1. However, when I try to insert the parents' information, I get a foreign key constraint that says it's not getting the id from Student_id, so I'm trying to insert it myself manually. The parent contains the same student_id as the student.

Comment: Ok. I think is an application problem because you need to know the student_id to insert the Parent record or Essay. So, it means that somehow previous to insert the parents you have to retrieve the Student_id based on the name (or similar).

Comment: ^^ Yes, this is what I'm trying to do. I need the student_ID to add Parents or Essay (that way the parents & the student's essay are linked to the right student) but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Updated again based on your queries.