# Copy values from one table to another

Tags: php, mysql

I am using mysql and during an insertion to Table A, I want to also insert some values to Table B. I tried using triggers, but I don't know how to make it work the way I want it to.

Say, I have a table set as products, and it has a field product_id. 
I have another table, products_metadata, which also has a field a product_id.

I want to be able insert into product_metadata before an insert into products, and I want to set products_metadata.product_id = products.product_id;

I thought triggers was the way to do it, but how do I do it?

Comment: Please show the trigger you have tried

Comment: Do the metadata insert after

Comment: The trigger I used was close to miserable I'd say. I think I have close to no idea on how to do this. Yes, doing the metada insert after is the only way I think, but how do I get the products.product_id is still the confusing part.

Comment: You should fetch values using select query from one table and insert that values to second table using insert query

Comment: @PiyushGupta But, what condition would I use to fetch that data? Something like MAX(product_id) hoping that the last entered row would be one? Or is there some other way of doing it?

Comment: you can refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540202/how-do-i-grab-info-from-one-table-while-still-adding-values/36540488#36540488 Or update dumy data also, what ever is your requirement so we can create query for you.

Comment: max(product_id) works for me. But I was concerned whether it is a stable solution. This might sound weird and funny :P, but if multiple users are uploading products at the same time, would this corrupt the table. But thanks. This is simply and what I was looking for.